# OL3: Setting map view center to geolocation.getCurrentPosition doesn't work

Tags: leaflet, openlayers-3, proj4js

When the application starts, I want to center the map view on the users current position. I have tried two different approaches and can't get them work. The first one worked properly in leaflet, but in the development process I have decided to use OL3 instead.

First approach (worked in leaflet):

```
  var myProjectionName = "EPSG:25832";
  proj4.defs(myProjectionName,
             "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs");

 var centerPosition;

 if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function (pos) {
                 centerPosition =             
                            ol.proj.transform(
                                     [position.coords.longitude,
                                      position.coords.latitude],
                                     'EPSG:4326', 
                                      myProjectionName);
        },
        function (err) {centerPosition = [724844,6178000];},
        {
            enableHighAccuracy: false,
            timeout: 5000,
            maximumAge: 1000  
        });
}
```

My second approach was using the ol.Geolocation class:

```
 var proj1 = ol.proj.get(myProjectionName);
 var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
                             projection: proj1
                       });
 var centerPosition= geolocation.getPosition();
```

The center position is used in creating the view/map object:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
   target: 'map',
   logo : false,
   layers: [ GSTGroup, OVLGroup, SheatLayer],
   view: new ol.View({
      projection: myProjectionName,
      center: centerPosition,
      resolutions : AVLresolutions,
      resolution : 2
     })
});
```

I have some suspecions that the cause of the problem is the projection, but on the other hand the projection works properly in transforming layers (WMTS, Vector), source from Geojson in different coordinatesystem and in ol.control.MousePosition.

I am using Firefox 32.0.3 and the geolocator plugin to development/test

Working example in http://jsfiddle.net/AndersFinn/ak4zotn8/

Comment: It is likely to be the projection. You are using UTM 32 for Southern Sweden/Norway area, in meters, and then loading vector data in 4326, presumably, and you want to use the former to set the center, correct? If you could provide a minimal working example in jsfiddle, including wms, it would help.

Comment: Hi John. a working example is added to the post. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add after the `map` declaration the following (tested):

```
var proj1 = ol.proj.get(myProjectionName);
var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
    projection: myProjectionName,
    tracking: true
});

geolocation.on('change', function(evt) {
  console.log(geolocation.getPosition());
  map.getView().setCenter(geolocation.getPosition());
});
```

The most important part is `tracking: true` in the code: it means you check regularly the position to center.

The second important part is to bind event on `geolocation` object (an instance of `ol.Geolocation`)

See in the [official examples](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/) the geolocation samples and the [API docs](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.Geolocation.html) to make some changes depending of your requirements